# pass opencv Mat(C++ version) to torch lua

Tags: c++, opencv, lua

How can I pass an instance of OpenCV's Mat written in C++ to torch lua?
Since a part of of the program is written in C++ to process the image to get a Mat, after which I need to pass that Mat to Lua for further processing by Lua.

Thanks a lot.